# Mutex not being respected in synchronized methods in Java class

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I'm running into mutex issues with my Queue class under load which I'm at a loss to figure out why they are happening.

```
objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
public synchronized int getSize(){
 return objects.size();
}

public synchronized Object dequeue(){
 if(getSize()==0){
  try {
   wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 return objects.remove(0);
}

public synchronized void enqueue(Object o){
 objects.add(o);
 notify();
}
```

It seems as if the dequeue method after a while is causing Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException which to me looks like threads have been able to call the dequeue method multiple times when it shouldnt be. Any ideas ???

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for `wait()` to return *without* another thread calling `notify()`, and that would explain the exception that you are seeing.

Try

```
while(getSize()==0)
```

and

```
notifyAll();
```

instead of

```
if(getSize()==0)
```

and

```
notify();
```

Comment: Cheers m8..
As a brief follow up my unit tests are obv not advanced enough to pick this up. Any methodologies you can recomend - I've been meaning to look into groboutils as junit isnt really suited to multithreading tests.

Comment: @imerez - ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When multiple threads are waiting in the dequeue method and wake up or get an InterruptedException (for a reason other than the notify) they will try to get an object off the queue even when it is empty.

If you change your method to be:

```
public synchronized Object dequeue(){
 while (getSize()==0){
  try {
   wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 return objects.remove(0);
}
```

the problem should be gone, and as a bonus you can use `notifyAll()` instead of relying on the behaviour of notify.

Comment: It's probably not an `InterruptedException`.  That would show up in the stack trace.